# Synonym request: [segfault] + [segmentationfault] into [segmentation-fault]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The term of [segmentationfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/segmentationfault) is often shortened to [segfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/segfault).

So, let's create new tag [segmentation-fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/segmentation-fault) ([for better readability](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/566/218590)) and make it synonym of two tags above.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That tag has been bothering me for a while. It's about time we fixed it.

Both tags have been synonymized and merged into [segmentation-fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/segmentation-fault).